# Automated Emails using Google Script

Tags: google-sheets, jakarta-mail

I have a data

Date         (Unmatched ad requests)    Anonymous   Branded Grand Total
01-07-2017  0                            59      50       100
02-07-2017  19580                        4602   6975    31157
03-07-2017  20924                        4843   7620    33387
04-07-2017  22686                        3894   6186    32766
05-07-2017  23015                        3476   4902    31393
06-07-2017  24108                        3812   5001    32921

```
function sendEmail() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = 50;   // Number of rows to process

var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 50);

// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
//Browser.msgBox(data)

for (i in data) {
var row = data[i];
{
  var emailAddress = row[5];  // First column
  var message = row[2];       // Second column
  var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
 // Browser.msgBox(emailAddress)

}

}

}
```

Can you help me to send the entire data in gmail using google scripts

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendEmail() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange()
  var data=dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++) 
  {
    var emailAddress = data[i][0];  // First column
    var message = data[i][1];       // Second column
    var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```